# NSTableView reload automatically when i resize window How to disable it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

`NSTableView` reload automatically when i resize window and i calculate something when table reload,now i have problem because it's reload automatically.how to disable it? i found below answer but doesn't work

```
[self.tbl setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you want to stop the table from reloading? What's the problem with doing the calculation? The code you posted has nothing to do with your problem, but if you want a good answer, you'll have to give more information.

Comment: I just want to know how to stop reloading until i call `[table reloadData]`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A table view does not have internal storage for the values in the table. It uses the data source as its storage.  If resizing the table view requires that it draw new rows or columns, or even redraw existing rows and columns, it must consult the data source to obtain the information necessary to do that.

What you're learning is that it is inappropriate to do expensive calculations in the data source methods.  From the documentation for `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`:

> tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: is called each time the table
>   cell needs to be redisplayed, so **it must be efficient**.

(Emphasis added.)